# SQL- Calculating SUM/COUNT with rows of table

Tags: sql

I have a PriceComparison table with (StoreNumber, ItemNumber, Price) that keeps pricing data for head-to-head comparison shopping. The goal is a recordset with the following things for all stores:

- StoreNumber
- COUNT of head-to-head wins for that store
- COUNT of head-to-head losses for that store
- COUNT of head-to-head ties for that store
- SUM of all item pricing for that store
- SUM of all head-to-head competitor pricing for items above for that store

Example:

```
StoreNumber  ItemNumber  Price
-----------  ----------  -----
101          1           1.39
102          1           1.89
101          2           3.49
103          2           2.99
101          3           9.99
104          3           9.99
```

I'm thinking I can calculate these SUMs and COUNTs if I can get a temporary column added for CompetitorPrice. That way, the item has both prices listed, and it becomes easy.

How can I get this information in the correct configuration? I tried an INNER JOIN to the same table, but that gets tricky.

Thanks!

UPDATE: This is for MS SQL Server.
UPDATE: There will only be two prices per item, no more than 2 stores.

Comment: What happens when there are entries like `102,2,2.99` as well?  Now you've got more than 2 stores that supply the same item.

Comment: What do you mean by the last two bullet points? Is it the sum of the price of all items for that particular store?

Comment: What SQL Product? And what's the expected output given your sample data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    a.storenumber,
    SUM(CASE WHEN a.price < b.price THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS wins,
    SUM(CASE WHEN a.price > b.price THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS losses,
    SUM(CASE WHEN a.price = b.price THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ties,
    SUM(a.price) AS store_price_sum,
    SUM(b.price) AS competitor_price_sum
FROM
    pricecomparison a
INNER JOIN
    pricecomparison b ON 
        a.itemnumber = b.itemnumber AND 
        a.storenumber <> b.storenumber
GROUP BY
    a.storenumber
```

Comment: If you are using a non-standard and not really widespread feature of a particular SQL product, it would be nice if you at least specified that. I'm talking about your use of implicit conversion of booleans to numbers. Even better would be to create a live demonstration [like this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/65a81/1), to show that this does work *before* the OP starts translating this to the particular SQL variety they use. Other than that, it's +1 from me on the working (albeit on a limited set of SQL products) example.

Comment: Yes, I could've used `CASE` expressions, but I thought the way I did it was more succinct. I'm not familiar with DBMSs outside of MySQL; could you perhaps tell me what particular DBMSs don't do that particular boolean conversion?

Comment: [Oracle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b91a9/1), [PostgreSQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/50f94/1), [SQL Server](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/50f94/1).

Comment: Oh wow, thanks. I will definitely keep that in mind when I'm on the `sql` tag! =)